# Getting the device address by device tree file in C

Tags: c, linux, kernel, device-tree

I am working on Linux; when Linux starts up
the DTS (device tree), the file will be loaded by Linux kernel.

My question is, is there have any way to get device address by DTS file using the C lanugage?

For example:

Some part of the DTS file is like:

```
soc@ffe00000{
    .......
    i2c@112000{
    .......
    }
}
```

I want to get device `name(soc,i2c)`，and `address(ffe00000,112000)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Hi CK vir,

Your question isn't very clear.  I'm assuming you are looking for some sort of function that takes as an argument the contents of the dts file and returns a bunch of (device, address) pairs.  Is that correct?

Also, it would be useful if you told us what sort of device you are using.  Is it a raspberry pi?  A beaglebone black?  or a full desktop computer?  What distro and version of linux are you using?

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but a while ago, I used a nice library posted [here on github](https://github.com/jviki/dtree).  For instance, to get the address for the device named "ethernet", you would do the following.

```
int err = dtree_open("/proc/device-tree");
if(err != 0)
{
    printf("failed to open device tree\n");
    exit(1);
}

struct dtree_dev_t *eth = dtree_byname("ethernet");
if(eth == 0)
{
    printf("failed to find device named \"ethernet\"\n");
    exit(1);
}

//print the base address of the ethernet hardware
printf("base address of ethernet is %i\n", eth->base);

dtree_dev_free(eth);

dtree_close();
```

I hope this library is as useful for you as it was for me.

If that doesn't help, it is a trivial task to implement a dts parser in C.  The "language" for dts isn't terribly complex.  A number of details regarding the syntax can be found [here](http://www.devicetree.org/Device_Tree_Usage).

Best,
John